# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\frac{x+1}{\left | x+1 \right |}$

Tags: limits

I suppose the *right hand limit* is $1$ and *left hand limit* is $0$. Is that correct?

Also, in a multiple choice question with the following options:

> The value of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\frac{x+1}{\left | x+1 \right |}$$  is either
>
> - (a) $1$
> - (b) $−1$
> - (c) $0$
> - (d) None of the above

Which one do I select, considering the right and left limits are different?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit from the right is $1$, not $0$.   The limit from the left is $-1$, not $1$.  They're unequal.

Comment: If you have a minute, please look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Furthermore, I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Got it! Thankyou kind strangers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must do case work, for $$x>-1$$ we have $$\frac{x+1}{|x+1|}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}=1$$
for $$x<-1$$ we have $$\frac{x+1}{|x+1|}=\frac{x+1}{-(x+1)}=-1$$ thus there is no Limit.

Comment: I see my mistake, thank's a ton!

Answer (score 2):

The limit exists iff the left hand limit equals the right hand limit. Since this is not the case,the answer is $(d)$ None of the above.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we approach from the right hand side, $x+1$ is positive:

Therefore:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+}\frac{x+1}{|x+1|}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+}\frac{x+1}{x+1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+}1=1$$

If we approach from the left hand side, $x+1$ is negative and equals $-|x+1|$.

Therefore: 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^-}\frac{x+1}{|x+1|}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^-}\frac{x+1}{-(x+1)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^-}-\frac{x+1}{x+1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^-}-1=-1$$

Therefore, the limits are different from the right hand side and the left hand side, and the limit does not exist.

Comment: If we approach from the left hand side, $x + 1$ is negative, while $|x + 1|$ is positive.

Comment: A minor quibble.  It looks like you meant to say that $x + 1$ is positive in your first sentence.